# Create third column based on comparing two columns and update data in each row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-structures

**Input:**
I want a filtered list with a new column such that:

**conditions:**

```
1) Filter out the dictionary if class == 'sc'
    then list_ contains all the "hsc" class records
2) Check if any duplicate ages have a status regular then update the dictionary with a new column "comment" as "NO"
3) Check if all duplicate ages have status private then update the dictionary with a new column "comment" as "YES"
4) Check if no duplicate age has status private then update the dictionary with a new column as "YES" else "NO"

    list_ = [
        {"name":'ekansh', "age": 10, "status": "private", "class": "sc"},
        {"name":'walt', "age": 12, "status": "private", "class": "hsc"},
        {"name":'harry', "age": 11, "status": "private", "class": "hsc"},
        {"name":'alex', "age": 11, "status": "private", "class": "hsc"},
        {"name":'rob', "age": 12, "status": "private", "class": "hsc"},
        {"name":'bob', "age": 12, "status": "regular", "class": "hsc"},
        {"name":'bob', "age": 9, "status": "private", "class": "hsc"},
    ]
```

**Expected  Output:**

```
list_ = [
        {"name":'walt', "age": 12, "status": "private", "class": "hsc", "comment": "NO"},
        {"name":'harry', "age": 11, "status": "private", "class": "hsc", "comment": "YES"},
        {"name":'alex', "age": 11, "status": "private", "class": "hsc", "comment": "YES"},
        {"name":'rob', "age": 12, "status": "private", "class": "hsc", "comment": "NO"},
        {"name":'bob', "age": 12, "status": "regular", "class": "hsc", "comment": "NO"},
        {"name":'bob', "age": 9, "status": "private", "class": "hsc", "column": "Yes"},
    ]
```

Advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I tried below. It is working but how to optimize more using DS/pandas/python.

```
aa = []
while(len(a)):
    for v in a:
        new = [j for j in a if v['age'] == j['age']]
        aa.append(new)
        [a.remove(i) for i in new]

final = [k.update({'comment':'Yes'}) if k['class'] == 'hsc' and all([j['status'] == 'private' for j in i]) else k.update({'comment': 'No'}) for i in aa for k in i]
res = sum(aa, [])
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I 'fully' understood the question, but hopefully this helps:

```
import pandas as pd

# First, define a function for updating a 'comment' column
def selector(x):
    if x['updated_status'] == 'private':
        return 'YES'
    else:
        return 'NO'

# convert list_ to Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(list_)

# Filter out class = "sc"
df = df[df['class'] != 'sc']

# Since we want to essentially update the status of 'age' duplicates with the 
# corresponding status value,  we can group by age first.
age_grouping = df[['age', 'status']]
age_grouping = age_grouping.groupby(['age'])['status'].apply(lambda x: list(np.unique(x))).reset_index()
age_grouping["updated_status"] = ["private" if ele  == ["private"] else "regular" for ele in age_grouping["status"]]
age_grouping = age_grouping.drop('status', axis=1)
df2 = pd.merge(df, age_grouping, on="age")

# create 'comment' column
df2 = df2.assign(flag=df2.apply(selector, axis=1))
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'flag': 'comment'})
df2 = df2.drop('updated_status', axis=1)

# Finally, if you want to convert the DataFrame back to a list of dicts
list_ = df2.T.to_dict().values()
```

Comment: It is not working as expected. It give 5 records but the 6th one should also be there ({"name":'bob', "age": 9, "status": "private", "class": "hsc"}). I liked this logic. Please correct it. @EarlofMar

Comment: I understand. Updated.